# Flexbox align with Angular Material custom design. Centering content removes width of content

Tags: css, flexbox, angular-material

So I've been working on a custom design for a site, using Angular Material as the base.

I have a problem with centering my content inside the container. When I center, the content shrinks instead of expanding like it normally does.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adVXay

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body layout="row" ng-controller="NavCtrl" id="main">
    <md-sidenav hidden-sm-xs class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2 md-locked-open of-navbar" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')" tabindex="-1">
        <header class="of-nav-topheader">
            SITE LOGO
        </header>
        <md-content flex role="navigation">
            <div>
                <md-button class="of-navbutton">
                    Menu Point 1
                </md-button>
                <md-button class="of-navbutton">
                    Menu Point 1
                </md-button>
                <md-button class="of-navbutton">
                    Menu Point 1
                </md-button>
                <md-button class="of-navbutton">
                    Menu Point 1
                </md-button>
                <button id="enable">Center Content</button>
                <button id="disable">Normal Layout</button>
            </div>
        </md-content>
    </md-sidenav>
    <div layout="column" tabindex="-1" role="main" flex>
        <md-toolbar class="md-whiteframe-glow-z1 site-content-toolbar of-site-toolbar" id="contentwrapper">
            <div layout-padding class="of-toolbar">
                <div class="md-toolbar-tools of-toolbar-tools">
                    <span>Toolbar</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </md-toolbar>
        <md-content layout-padding md-scroll-y layout="column" flex style="background:#f1f1f1" id="content">
            <div class="of-section">
                <md-content>
                    <md-list>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                <h3>Projectname</h3>
                                <h4>Projectnumber</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                    </md-list>
                </md-content>
            </div>
        </md-content>
    </div>
</body>
```

I added buttons in the navbar to add and remove the classes in Angular Material for centering content.

Thanks!

Comment: So, I actually fixed it myself.... Partially. Now the scrollbar is causing a misalignment...

Comment: Codepen updated with fix.

Comment: Your html says id="fix1", your css says .fix1 for example

Comment: I don't think you have and understanding how flex works https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and http://flexbox.io/#/ are a good start

Comment: @CarolMcKay, those are just helper classes i added to make the buttons work. But yeah, Like it says in my comments, I actually fixed it by restructuring my layout. I know how to use flexboxes to an extent, but the problem in this case is the classes in the Angular Material framework which seems to confuse me. Thanks for taking time to have a look anyways :)